# Flutter - FlutterWebAuth Spotify

Tags: android, flutter, oauth-2.0, spotify

I have my application setup in Spotify. I tried to use flutter_web_auth package to get access_tokens & refresh_token, however, I have a router(?) problem

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qify/env.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_auth/flutter_web_auth.dart';

Future main() async {
  await dotenv.load();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => const MyHomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  void keyPress() async {
    var redirectUri = Uri.https('accounts.spotify.com', '/authorize', {
      'client_id': Env.clientId, //"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      "response_type": "code",
      "redirect_uri": Env.redirectUri, // "qify:/"
      "scope": [].join(" "),
      "show_dialog": "true",
    });

    final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
      url: redirectUri.toString(),
      callbackUrlScheme: Env.callbackUrlScheme, // "qify"
    );

    print(result);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [Text("test")],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: keyPress,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have setup AndroidManifest.xml as so

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.qify">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:label="qify" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth" android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="qify" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Upon return, I get this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by Flutter framework ═════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/?code=xxxxxxxxxx"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead.

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Which I suppose is not exactly "/" so my app can't find it... I don't know where to search for now

I've been looking at those links : [Flutter: Oauth2 - Problems with redirect uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244209/flutter-oauth2-problems-with-redirect-uri) & [Flutter Spotify Api Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554240/flutter-spotify-api-authentication)

Can't find what I'm lacking :/